# Training Graph Neural Network (GNN) to create Embeddings using spektral

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I am working to create a Graph Neural Network (GNN) which can create embeddings of the input graph for its usage in other applications like Reinforcement Learning.

I have started with example from the spektral library [TUDataset classification with GIN](https://github.com/danielegrattarola/spektral/blob/master/examples/graph_prediction/tud_gin.py) and modified it to divide the network into two parts. The first part to produce embeddings and second part to produce classification. My goal is to train this network using supervised learning on dataset with graph labels e.g. TUDataset and use the first part (embedding generation) once trained in other applications.

I am getting different results from my approach in two different datasets. The TUDataset shows improved loss and accuracy with this new approach whereas the other other local dataset shows significant increase in the loss.

Can I get any feedback if my approach to create embedding is appropriate or any suggestions for further improvement?

here is my code used to generate graph embeddings:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.losses import CategoricalCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_accuracy
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

from spektral.data import DisjointLoader
from spektral.datasets import TUDataset
from spektral.layers import GINConv, GlobalAvgPool

################################################################################
# PARAMETERS
################################################################################
learning_rate = 1e-3  # Learning rate
channels = 128  # Hidden units
layers = 3  # GIN layers
epochs = 300  # Number of training epochs
batch_size = 32  # Batch size

################################################################################
# LOAD DATA
################################################################################
dataset = TUDataset("PROTEINS", clean=True)

# Parameters
F = dataset.n_node_features  # Dimension of node features
n_out = dataset.n_labels  # Dimension of the target

# Train/test split
idxs = np.random.permutation(len(dataset))
split = int(0.9 * len(dataset))
idx_tr, idx_te = np.split(idxs, [split])
dataset_tr, dataset_te = dataset[idx_tr], dataset[idx_te]

loader_tr = DisjointLoader(dataset_tr, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
loader_te = DisjointLoader(dataset_te, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=1)

################################################################################
# BUILD MODEL
################################################################################
class GIN0(Model):
    def __init__(self, channels, n_layers):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = GINConv(channels, epsilon=0, mlp_hidden=[channels, channels])
        self.convs = []
        for _ in range(1, n_layers):
            self.convs.append(
                GINConv(channels, epsilon=0, mlp_hidden=[channels, channels])
            )
        self.pool = GlobalAvgPool()
        self.dense1 = Dense(channels, activation="relu")

    def call(self, inputs):
        x, a, i = inputs
        x = self.conv1([x, a])
        for conv in self.convs:
            x = conv([x, a])
        x = self.pool([x, i])
        return self.dense1(x)


# Build model
model = GIN0(channels, layers)
model_op = Sequential()
model_op.add(Dropout(0.5, input_shape=(channels,)))
model_op.add(Dense(n_out, activation="softmax"))
opt = Adam(lr=learning_rate)
loss_fn = CategoricalCrossentropy()


################################################################################
# FIT MODEL
################################################################################
@tf.function(input_signature=loader_tr.tf_signature(), experimental_relax_shapes=True)
def train_step(inputs, target):
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        node2vec = model(inputs, training=True)
        predictions = model_op(node2vec, training=True)
        loss = loss_fn(target, predictions)
        loss += sum(model.losses)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    gradients2 = tape.gradient(loss, model_op.trainable_variables)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients2, model_op.trainable_variables))
    acc = tf.reduce_mean(categorical_accuracy(target, predictions))
    return loss, acc


print("Fitting model")
current_batch = 0
model_lss = model_acc = 0
for batch in loader_tr:
    lss, acc = train_step(*batch)

    model_lss += lss.numpy()
    model_acc += acc.numpy()
    current_batch += 1
    if current_batch == loader_tr.steps_per_epoch:
        model_lss /= loader_tr.steps_per_epoch
        model_acc /= loader_tr.steps_per_epoch
        print("Loss: {}. Acc: {}".format(model_lss, model_acc))
        model_lss = model_acc = 0
        current_batch = 0

################################################################################
# EVALUATE MODEL
################################################################################
def tolist(predictions):
    result = []
    for item in predictions:
        result.append((float(item[0]), float(item[1])))
    return result
loss_data = []
print("Testing model")
model_lss = model_acc = 0
for batch in loader_te:
    inputs, target = batch
    node2vec = model(inputs, training=False)
    predictions = model_op(node2vec, training=False)
    predictions_list = tolist(predictions)
    loss_data.append(zip(target,predictions_list))
    model_lss += loss_fn(target, predictions)
    model_acc += tf.reduce_mean(categorical_accuracy(target, predictions))
model_lss /= loader_te.steps_per_epoch
model_acc /= loader_te.steps_per_epoch
print("Done. Test loss: {}. Test acc: {}".format(model_lss, model_acc))
for batchi in loss_data:
    for item in batchi:
        print(list(item),'\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to generate graph embeddings is correct, the `GIN0` model will return a vector given a graph.

This code here, however, seems weird:

```py
gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
gradients2 = tape.gradient(loss, model_op.trainable_variables)
opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients2, model_op.trainable_variables))
```

What you're doing here is that you're updating the weights of `model` twice, and the weights of `model_op` once.

When you compute the loss in the context of a `tf.GradientTape`, all computations that went into computing the final value are tracked. This means that if you call `loss = foo(bar(x))` and then compute the training step using that loss, the weights of both `foo` and `bar` will be updated.

Besides this, I don't see issues with the code so it will mostly depend on the local dataset that you are using.

Cheers